# Temporary .jack file aborting execution in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently compiled a program on android studio, but now when I try to run it on the device, I get this error. I recently updated to android studio 2.2.2

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForRelease'.

> Failed to delete temporary file C:\Users\Mylap\AppData\Local\Temp\jill-1477155003111-0.jack